# nodejs: Async.series only executes the first function and stops

Tags: javascript, node.js

On executing the following code, only first function of the async.series executes.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var async = require("async");
var buffer = new Buffer(10);
var read = "";
var readByt;
async.series([      
    function(callback) {
         console.log("console: 1");
    },
    function (callback){
        console.log("console: 2");
    }
],function(){});
```

The output is given below:

```
c:\>node fr.js
}}}c:/log.txt
File closed successfully.
```

If the following is edited as mentioned below:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var async = require("async");
var buffer = new Buffer(10);
var read = "";
var readByt;
async.series([
    function(callback) {
         console.log("test");
    },
    function (callback){
        console.log("console: 1");
    }
   function (callback){
        console.log("console: 2");
    }
],function(){});
```

The output changes as below:

```
c:\>node fr.js
test
```

How do i get all the functions in the async.series to execute?

Comment: Looks like you're not calling the `callback` function to let `async.series` know when each function is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to invoke the `callback` argument supplied in the array of functions to instruct the `async` module to invoke the next function.

Answer (score 1):

```
var fs = require("fs");
var async = require("async");
var buffer = new Buffer(10);
var read = "";
var readByt;
async.series([      
    function(callback) {
        fs.open('c:/ab.txt', 'r+', function(err, fd) {
            fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, 0, function(err, bytes){
                read = buffer.slice(0, bytes).toString();
                readByt = bytes;        
                console.log("}}}"+read);
                fs.close(fd, function(err){
                    if (err){
                    console.log(err);
                    } 
                    console.log("File closed successfully.");           
                })
            })
        })
```

> ```
>      //invoke here for continue and to break use callback(false);
>      callback()
> ```

```
    },
    function (callback){
        console.log("console:"+read);
        console.log("console:"+read.substr(read.length-1));
        console.log("console:"+buffer.slice(0, readByt).toString());
    }
],function(){});
```